# Extracting a year from a string in a column in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column titled SALE_PERIOD, which stores a string relating to when and where a product is sold. The column is filled using the following conventions:

1. Two letters, which represents the month the sale was made
2. The year the sale was made
3. The number of the store where the sale occurred

For example, a product sold in JAN 2018 at store number 5 would be stored as "JA20185"

I need a query which will extract the year the sale was made from this column and allow me to write it into a new column in the following way:

```
SELECT SALE_PERIOD, (The code used to solve the problem) AS SALE_YEAR
FROM My_Table
```

I am aware the final code may need to look slightly different and any alternative solutions are also greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for `SUBSTR(SALE_PERIOD,3,4)` ?

Comment: Looks like you require the built-in function [SUBSTR](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/substr.php) which is part of Oracle SQL.

Comment: How do you distinct **JU**ne and **JU**ly Or **MA**y and **MA**rch?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - maybe they close the store for three months and don't sell anything in May, June or July?

Comment: Or maybe they store it as `JN` = June, `JL` = July, `MY` = May and `MR` = March?

Answer (score 3):

Use `SUBSTR` to get the 4-character year substring starting from the 3rd character and then convert it to a number:

```sql
SELECT sale_period,
       TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR( sale_period, 3, 4 ) ) AS sale_year,
       -- and for the other components:
       SUBSTR( sale_period, 1, 2 ) AS sale_month,
       TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR( sale_period, 7 ) ) AS sale_store
FROM   my_table;
```

outputs:

> ```
> SALE_PERIOD | SALE_YEAR | SALE_MONTH | SALE_STORE
> :---------- | --------: | :--------- | ---------:
> JA20185     |      2018 | JA         |          5
> DE2019123   |      2019 | DE         |        123
> ```

Since the `SALE_PERIOD` column has a well specified format for the sub-strings you could also add virtual columns to the table:

```sql
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD (
  sale_year  NUMBER(4,0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR( sale_period, 3, 4 ) ) ) VIRTUAL,
  sale_month CHAR(2)     GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( CAST( SUBSTR( sale_period, 1, 2 ) AS CHAR(2) ) ) VIRTUAL,
  sale_store NUMBER(5,0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR( sale_period, 7 ) ) ) VIRTUAL
)
```

then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table;
```

gives the same output as above with those additional virtual columns.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/markdown?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=efd499a11f312c93317e6d6ea9229e47)*

Answer (score 0):

You can split through `[^[:digit:]]` posix pattern by using `regexp_substr()` and  `regexp_replace()` functions' combination :

```
with my_table( sale_period ) as
(
 select 'a product sold in JAN 2018 at store number 5' from dual
)
select substr(substr(trim(regexp_substr(sale_period,'[^[:digit:]]+')),-3),1,2) 
       ||regexp_replace(sale_period,'[^[:digit:]]') as sale_year
  from my_table
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9191cbd987c2dcd1733b302a4ab0aa68)</kbd>